# Adding recommended dependency by linter results in an infinite re-rendering loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, dependencies

Here's my code:

**SectionState.js:**

```
import { React, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import QuestionContext from "./QuestionContext";
import questions from "../data/questions.json";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const SectionState = (props) => {

    // set questions from json to an array of 4 elements
    const newQuestions = Object.keys(questions.content).map(
        (key) => questions.content[key].question
    );

    //useState for Question state
    const [currentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion] = useState(0);
    const newQuestionsArr = {
        qID: 0,
        questionTxt: newQuestions[currentQuestion],
    }
    const [questionCtx, setQuestionCtx] = useState(newQuestionsArr);
    const navigate = useNavigate()

    useEffect(() => {
        setQuestionCtx(prevState => ({
            ...prevState,
            qID: currentQuestion,
            questionTxt: newQuestions[currentQuestion], 
        }));
    }, [currentQuestion]);

    const updateNextQuestion = () => {
        if (!(currentQuestion >= newQuestions.length)) {
            setCurrentQuestion((nextCurrentQuestion) => nextCurrentQuestion + 1);
        }
        else{
            navigate('/result')
        }
    };

    const updatePrevQuestion = () => {
        if (currentQuestion <= 0) {
            console.log(`No more questions`);
        } else {
            setCurrentQuestion((prevCurrentQuestion) => prevCurrentQuestion - 1);
        }
    };

    return (
        <QuestionContext.Provider
            value={{ questionCtx, updateNextQuestion, updatePrevQuestion }}>
            {props.children}
        </QuestionContext.Provider>
    );
};

export default SectionState;
```

Linter throws the following warning

> React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'newQuestions'. Either include it or remove the dependency array

If I add newQuestions in the dependency array, it results in re-rendering loop. I can't declare either newQuestions or questionCtx state inside useEffect as it is used elsewhere in the code.

I can see that I have to update the `questionTxt`. What should I do here to update the said value and remove the warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A new `newQuestions` object is created at every render. `usEffect` is triggered when one of the dependencies changes. Hence the infinite render loop.

1. If the `newQuestions` is a constant that depends on a json you import from a file, you could move it outside of the component as mentioned in @CertainPerformance answer. [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-tesla-fknr1p?file=/src/App.tsx)
2. If for some reasons you want to declare the `newQuestions` variable inside of your component, you could use [`useMemo`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) hook. [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/throbbing-firefly-irfw5v?file=/src/App.tsx)
3. You could disable the lint rule which is probably not a good idea.

I'm not really sure what you trying to achieve, but it seems like you probably don't need the `useEffect` and might have some redundant states.

Maybe you could use only one state, and get rid of the `useEffect`. You only need one state to keep track of the current question, and calculate other variables in each render.

```
  const [currentQuestion, setCurrentQuestion] = React.useState(0);

  const questionCtx = React.useMemo(
    () => ({
      qId: currentQuestion,
      questionTxt: newQuestions[currentQuestion]
    }),
    [currentQuestion]
  );
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-shannon-3fst6s?file=/src/App.tsx)

You could read more about [managing state](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/managing-state) in the react beta documentation.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `newQuestions` array is computed anew each time the function runs, and so won't be `===` to the old array (and so will run every render). If `newQuestions` depended on other React values, the usual fix would be to memoize it with `useMemo`, but because it looks to depend only on a static imported value, you may as well just declare it outside the component (which means it doesn't need to be a dependency anymore either).

It also looks like you don't care about the keys, only the values - so, easier to use `Object.values` than `Object.keys`.

```
import { React, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import QuestionContext from "./QuestionContext";
import questions from "../data/questions.json";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

const newQuestions = Object.values(questions.content).map(
    val => val.question
);
```

Comment: Okay, I did the changes as recommended and put newQuestions in dependency array again, yet it still results in an infinite re rendering loop, throwing infinite errors.

Comment: If you `question` is imported from a file, and you create `newQuestions` variable outside of the function, there's no need to put it in the array of dependencies. [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/beautiful-tesla-fknr1p?file=/src/App.tsx).